# socket.io client doesn't set sid in requests

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm trying to build a nodejs script to communicate with a socket.io server.

```
const io = require('socket.io-client');
const socket = io('http://192.168.144.249');

socket.on('connect', () => {
  console.log('connected');
})
```

Using wireshark to follow traffic I can see the following:

[image: receiving sid and cookie]

So the browser sends me a sid, both in the response body and in the cookie.
Unfortunately, my following requests do not include this sid and I received a `400 Bad Request` error:

[image]

When I try to build the same client from a browser windows I can see that this cookie is indeed set, both as cookie and as a query parameter:

[image]

I don't want to use a browser, I want to use a standalone node script. As far as I understood the parsing of the response and the inclusion of the session id should be done automatically by the `socket.io-client`. Am I wrong? If so, how can I intercept this event so that I can send the sid with following requests?

Am I supposed to first do a simple http request to the server, get the sid from there and then add it to the socket.io client when creating it using custom cookies or custom query parameters?

I can also see that the node standalone script is using engine.io version 4 (`EIO=4` in the GET requests), while the browser is doing it with engine.io version 3, but the respose received seems to be exactly the same so I don't really think this is what is preventing my script from automatically completing the handshake with the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I was wrong. It was indeed a protocol mismatch problem.

I was able to make my script working using `socket.io-client@1.0.2`. Install it with:

`npm install socket.io-client@1.0.2`